# How Do I Post on Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

No No wait... This is not a "How do I google something?" Question. I'm rather asking about what rules there are when posting on meta? I mean on the main site you can roughly say: Post Questions that are clear and answerable by gamers and post answers that are accurate and easily understandable. These rules are written down in the FAQ and they are clear.

I just feel that meta doesn't really have these "strict" rules and yet at the same time they are somehow there. But just not as clear as on the main site.

How exactly should I create my meta post for the different tags? Can a Meta Question already start with the answer in the meta head? I often see that but i'm not completely sure if it's good. Can there be Multiple Questions in a meta post (Like in this one)?

How broad can the meta Questions be and when are Meta Questions closed or deleted?

Also when answering what are the guidelines? I mean Meta is made for opinion based content but what is the correct way to answer meta questions?

Comment: A good place to start would be [What is Meta](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta); many of the rules which apply to Arqade apply to Meta, questions still need to be clear and concise etc etc, however the subject is instead the improvment of Arqade. Also the voting is more a For and Against rather than Bad or good question/answer.

Comment: Congrats, you just did. In the future, should you wish to do so again, just repeat the steps you took this time.

Comment: As far at the "Can there be Multiple Questions in a meta post" I would say "Only if they are related".  This rule seems to be the same between Main and Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of this myself (which is why I haven't posted here before), but StackExchange's [page on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) might be useful. Note that the page is specifically for Meta Stack Exchange, but I believe that some of it is applicable here. I summarise the page here, to avoid this being a link only answer.

> Meta is for:
>
> - asking questions about how the websites work
> - asking questions of the community
> - posting bugs
> - suggesting improvements
> - proposing new features
> - Lots of topics are fair game
> - Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves
> - On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.